# How to change permission of a folder to 777 in Dockerfile?

Tags: linux, nginx, permissions, docker, file-permissions

I have a project directory like this:

```
|-var/www
|-docker-compose.yml
|-app
|--uploads
|---photos
|-Dockerfile
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
myapp:
    build:
      context: myfolder
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: flask
    image: api/v1:01
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      APP_ENV: "prod"
      APP_DEBUG: "False"
      APP_PORT: 5000
    volumes:
      - appdata:/var/www
```

**What I want:** 
I want to change `app/uploads/photos` this folder's permission to `777`.This is an upload folder,so user can upload to this folder.

My `Dockerfile` now is look like this:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.9

ENV GROUP_ID=1000 \
    USER_ID=1000

WORKDIR /var/www/
ADD . /var/www/

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev ncurses-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN addgroup -g $GROUP_ID www
RUN adduser -D -u $USER_ID -G www www -s /bin/sh

USER www

EXPOSE 5000
```

After looking in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45972608/4332049),In order to achieve what I want,I tried below:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.9

ENV GROUP_ID=1000 \
    USER_ID=1000

WORKDIR /var/www/
ADD . /var/www/

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev ncurses-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN addgroup -g $GROUP_ID www
RUN adduser -D -u $USER_ID -G www www -s /bin/sh

RUN chown -R www:www /var/www
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/uploads
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/uploads/photos


USER www

EXPOSE 5000
```

But seems like the `chmod` command in my dockerfile is not taking effect.Cause whenever I upload some files to `app/uploads/photos` in my code,my `nginx` server keep getting this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/uploads/photos/myfilename.png'
```

Somebody please help.Please provide a solution for how to change the permission of a folder in `Dockerfile`.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to change the permission of `/var/www/uploads` after build the container and the container is running by doing below:

```
docker exec -it myapp /bin/sh
```

then run

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/uploads
```

What I get is `chmod: /var/www/uploads: Operation not permitted`

Therefore I suspect the this error will also happened when the docker is building,then according to [this answer from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/641282/463850), I tried to modify the dockerfile to this:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.9


ENV GROUP_ID=1000 \
    USER_ID=1000

WORKDIR /var/www/
ADD . /var/www/

USER root
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/uploads

RUN addgroup -g $GROUP_ID www
RUN adduser -D -u $USER_ID -G www www -s /bin/sh

USER www

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev ncurses-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 5000
```

But it still doesnt work. But seem like my above approach is also wrong.Cause I already run in `root` in the `dockerfile`.But at the same time,when I access the container in host using `docker exec`,also getting `Operation not permitted`.

I am very new in Docker.Just cant figure it out how to get this done.

**What I hope to know:**

1) How to change the folder `var/www/uploads` to permission 777?

2) What is the problem causing I cant change the permission from my approach?

3) What is the better way to achieve this? (If any)

Comment: It's already in the accepted answer, but let's still point this out separately, with additional emphasis: You should **basically _never_ use `chmod 777`** - it is insecure and clumsy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really shouldn't set `777`, it would probably be better to just change the ownership of that directory to the `www` account.

Anyway your changes in the Dockerfile really don't matter, because you have a volume (`appdata:/var/www`) meaning that the permissions you have in the image are masked by your volume.

Your `docker exec -it myapp /bin/sh` would be failing because that image is running as `www` which won't be able to run chmod on file not owned by `www`.

Anyway try just mapping volume into another image temporarily.  Do something like `docker run --rm -it -v appdata:/var/www debian:buster-slim` to start an interactive session to a Debian image with the volume mapped in. That image defaults to running as root, so you should be able to change/fix permissions in the volume.  You could also pass the `--user` option when when running your docker exec.

Comment: omg..omfg...it works!!!!!! Really thank you very much..at the end I able to change the ownership by pass `--user` option as `root` during the `docker exec` operation..

Comment: but just 1 more quick question,for ur second point of `the permissions you have in the image are masked by your volume`.For this,if I dont have `appdata:/var/www`,then my `Dockerfile` should work right?(means the permission will changed to 777) .Now it dont works is because I have a volume,and the `Dockerfile` cant change the permission of the volume..am I right?

Comment: I mean, the permissions in your Dockerfile **DOES work** from the point of view that the permissions ARE changed in the image, but you are mounting your volume on top of the existing files hiding them.  The volume would even work if you were starting with a **brand new** volume, since docker will copy things the first time a new volume is attached. when the container is started.

Comment: You saved my life! I was scratching my head for days and hours. Thanks!